# Argue for or against that the Fourier series for $f(x) = 6x+2$ converges uniformly and/or uniformly

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in $C{st}$ which satisfies that
$$
f(x) = 6x+2
$$
when $-\pi < x < \pi$. Then I have to argue for or against if the Fourier series converges pointwise or uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. I have asked this question before but as $C{st}$ is not common notation I hope I can get some more answers when defining what it means.

I would very much like to know how to tackle these kinds of questions as they most definitely will be a part of my Analysis Exam in three weeks.

Definition: Let $C{st}$ be the set of the functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies that

1. $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic
2. $f$ is piecewise continuous on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$
3. $f$ is normalized in its points of discontinunation

Futhermore we also need the following:

Definition: Let $C^1{st}$ be the set of the functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies

1. $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic
2. $f$ is piecewise differentiable on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$
3. $f$ is normalized in its points of discontinunation

Then my book says that:

Definition: The Fourier series for a function $f \in C^1{st}$ converges pointwise towards $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$

and

Definition: If $f \in C^1{st}$ and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then the Fourier series for $f$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

I have earlier said that $f(x)$ indeed is continuous as it is a composition of well-known continuous functions. Thus the following limits exist
$$
\lim{x \rightarrow \pi^-} 6x+2 = 6\pi + 1
$$
and
$$
\lim{x \rightarrow -\pi^+} 6x+2 = -6\pi + 1
$$
which means that $f(x)$ is continous in $\pm \pi$. But doesn't this mean that $f(x)$ is not $2\pi$-periodic? As $f(\pi) \neq f(-\pi)$ and how can I use this to argue for or against if the Fourier series for $f$ converges pointwise or uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Do you mind helping me?